# Include problems using pygame

Tags: python, include, pygame

I just started python, and more precisely pygame, and I found myself unable to do a very simple thing:
importing a file.

Here's the code:

Main file:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from cTile import Tile


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True
        self._display_surf = None
        self._image_surf = None
        self._x = 0
        self._y = 0
        self.tiles = []

    def on_init(self):
        pygame.init()
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((350,350), pygame.HWSURFACE)
        self._running = True
        #self._image_surf = pygame.image.load("myimage.jpg").convert()
        self._image_surf = pygame.image.load("myimage.jpg").convert()
        self.tiles = [Tile(0,0,0,0),Tile(1,0,64,0),Tile(0,1,0,64),Tile(1,1,64,64)]
        m = open("map1.map",'r')
        r = m.read().split(",")
        for i in range(len(r)/4):
            self.tiles.append(Tile(int(r[i*4]),int(r[i*4+1]),int(r[i*4+2]),int(r[i*4+3])))
            i = i+3

    def on_event(self, event):
        if event.type == QUIT:
            self._running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            self.key_event(event)

    def key_event(self,event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self._y = self._y+16
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self._y = self._y-16
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self._x = self._x+16
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self._x = self._x-16
    def on_loop(self):
        pass
    def on_render(self):
        self._display_surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
        for tile in self.tiles:
            tile.render(self)
        self._display_surf.blit(self._image_surf,(self._x,self._y), pygame.Rect(0, 0, 16, 16) )
        pygame.display.flip()

    def on_cleanup(self):
        pygame.quit()

    def on_execute(self):
        if self.on_init() == False:
            self._running = False

        while( self._running ):

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.on_event(event)
            self.on_loop()
            self.on_render()
        self.on_cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    theApp = App()
    theApp.on_execute()
```

The file I include:

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self,_pidx,_pidy,_px,_py):
        self._image_surf = pygame.image.load("myimage.jpg").convert()
        self._idx = _pidx
        self._idy = _pidy
        self._x = _px
        self._y = _py
    def render(self,win):
        win._display_surf.blit(self._image_surf,(self._x,self._y), pygame.Rect(self._idx*16, self._idy*16, self._idx*16+16, self._idy*16+16) )
```

And finally the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\test.py", line 70, in <module>
    theApp.on_execute()
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\test.py", line 57, in on_execute
    if self.on_init() == False:
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\test.py", line 22, in on_init
    self.tiles = [Tile(0,0,0,0),Tile(1,0,64,0),Tile(0,1,0,64),Tile(1,1,64,64)]
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\cTile.py", line 3, in __init__
    self._image_surf = pygame.image.load("myimage.jpg").convert()
NameError: global name 'pygame' is not defined
```

I'm learning the language right now. I tried to import pygame to my cTile.py file, and tried to use the `pygame.init()` right after, and still got the same error.

I though the import was doing the same thing an include would in php, but it is apparently not!

The code in itself may hurt anyone with little knowledge of python, but once again I started one hour ago and there are still many things that I have to fix up, the current main issue being this include I cannot fully understand! Thanks in advance for any help provided!

**EDIT:** When the code contained in cTile.py was just pasted above "Class App:" everything was running smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `import pygame` in your `cTile.py` file. Modules don't inherit the modules their clients may (or may not) have imported.

Comment: Indeed, as i said i tried that but i might now have saved the file because it didn't worked! Retried once again, saved, and it went perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: It's relevant to understand that imported modules are cached in `sys.modules` and any subsequent `import`s of the same one will use the stored value instead of reading and executing all the code contained in one again — so it's not very expensive to import the same one multiple times.

Comment: That is indeed a nice thing to know, i feared abusing the import procedure but i guess it wont be a problem if everything is cached, juste have to make sure not to import things that have nothing to do there! Thanks once again!